# С++ Работа с массивами (vector)

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Я только начинаю изучать язык С++. Не могу разобраться с задачей.
Есть 10 товаров и цены к ним. Нужно что бы пользователь ввел название товара и цену товара и количество штук.

```
struct Product_name
{
    std::string name;
    double price = 0;
    std::string piece;
    double quantity = 0;
    double result = 0;
};
 
Product_name addProduct()
{
    Product_name pr;
    std::cout << "Введите название продутка: ";
    std::cin >> pr.name;
    std::cout << "\nВведите цену продукта: ";
    std::cin >> pr.price;
    std::cout << "\nВведите количесво продуктов: ";
    std::cin >> pr.quantity;
    std::cout << "\n";
    pr.result = pr.price * pr.quantity;
    return pr;
}
 
void printProducts(std::vector<Product_name> v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << i << ") " << v[i].name << " - " << v[i].price << " ,количество: " << v[i].piece << ". Цена: " << v[i].result << " Br" << "\n";
}
 
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
 
    std::array<Product_name, 10> arr_product{{ {"Хлеб", 0.9, "(одна булка)"}, {"Белый хлеб", 1.1, "(одна булка)"},
                                               {"Молоко", 1.3, "(один пакет)"}, {"Масло", 3.6, "(одна укакова)"},
                                               {"Сметана", 1.8, "(один пакет)"}, {"Мясо", 16, "(один килограм)"},
                                               {"Апальчины", 3, "(один килограм)"}, {"Яблоки", 2.5, "(один килограм)"},
                                               {"Сахар", 2.05, "(один килограм)"}, {"Макароны", 1.29, "(одна упаковка)"} }};
 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_product.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << i << ") " << arr_product[i].name << " - " << arr_product[i].price << " " << arr_product[i].piece << "\n";
 
    std::vector<Product_name> products;
    
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Хотите ввести продукт? 1 - да, 0 - нет: ";
        std::cin >> i;
        std::cout << "\n";
        if (i == 0)
            break;
        products.push_back(addProduct());
        std::cout << "Введённый продукт: \n";
        printProducts(products);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

А далее надо посчитать скидку.

> В магазине действуют акции. На молочные продукты скидка 33%, на мучные 24% и 50% на продукт из корзины с максимальной стоимостью. Т.е. если у нас в корзине 5 буханок хлеба, пачка масла и две упаковки макарон, то продукт с максимальной стоимостью - хлеб (5 * 0.9 > 1 * 3.6 > 2 * 1.29). Необходимо написать программу, которая рассчитывает стоимость корзины покупателя с учетом акций. Акция к продукту может применяться только одна. Акция с максимально стоимостью имеет приоритет по отношению к остальным. Т.е. в примере выше хлеб попадает под две акции: мучные продукты и максимальный продукт соответственно учитывается только скидка на максимальный продукт из корзины. Если максимальных несколько, то пользователь должен выбрать к какому будет применена максимальная акция

Я не понимаю как это можно сделать помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала посчитай самый дорогой товар, и сделай ему сидку 50%, потом сделай скидку для мучных и молочных. При одинаковой стоимости акционных товаров сделай вывод списка и выбор. Потом сложи.